# Video Identification - Boy, Girl Two Pianos

Tags: nodame-cantabile

I'm trying to identify a video that I only saw a small part of (in the AMV room at A-Kon).  The part of the video I saw featured a boy and a girl and two pianos.  I think this might be enough to identify the video, but if it helps the AMV was to the Lady Antebellum song, Just a Kiss.  I can find the credits on Youtube but I don't see where it mentions the name of the video.

Comment: Do you have a Youtube link to the video you saw? It would probably be very helpful and make it easier for people to visually recognize the anime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The video title is "A Kiss Goodnight" by Dragon/Roy ([youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWMtjqu4SFo)) and the anime is [Nodame Cantabile](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=7010). The two characters you see playing the piano are Shinichi Chiaki (male) and Megumi Noda (female).